# ContentChildren doesn't get children created with NgTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, angular-components

In angular 5 i came across the following problem.

```
 <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-template>
```

[Bug plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1sIfVFq6Ra5UIcRw8Von?p=preview)

I was unable to select any component that i used in to  tag.

After some research i found a possible workaround

[Workaround plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1sIfVFq6Ra5UIcRw8Von?p=preview)

Now i wonder if there is any more convenient way to get the children?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your plunker it appears that you are attempting to access view children with [@ContentChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) while you should be using [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren). Here is an example:

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTpl"></ng-container>

<ng-template #myTpl>
  <hello></hello>
  <hello></hello>
</ng-template>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
 })
 export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   @ViewChildren(HelloComponent)
   helloComponets: QueryList<HelloComponent>;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     // access your components here
     console.log(this.helloComponets)
  }
}
```

See running example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p9tvxe?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Child elements within a component template are called "view children":

**my-component.html**

```
<my-view-child></my-view-child>
```

Child elements between the opening and closing tag of your component are called "content children":

```
<my-component>
  <my-content-child></my-content-child>
</my-component>
```